# Code works fine in emulator but gives error in real device?

Tags: android

I am building a chat app and I am using one account on emulator (Google Pixel 2 Api 30) and second on Realme 5 (Android 10). Now I have to choose multiple images from gallery so I use this piece of code.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setType("image/*");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

Now this code works perfectly fine in emulator but gives error in Realme 5.

Note: I don't know what error it gives on real device. The app just gets back to starting activity.

Comment: please check the logcat with no filter

Comment: probably default image picker on realme device is kind of broken, maybe doesn't support multiple picks at once... more "chinese" device manufacturer = more compatibility problems... :/

Comment: @snachmsm There is no default image. it always goes to pick image

Comment: Can you try on a different real device from a different manufacturer? Maybe it's an issue specific to Realme devices or as previous comment said the default gallery app on that device. You could also try a different gallery app on the same device. This will narrow down the problem more.

Comment: @miva2 ok I will try that

Comment: @M.Ahmed I've wrote "default image picker" not "default image" - I was talking about app which opens for picking images. Try to install another app, maybe common Photos app from Google (and set it as default image handler/picker, it probably ask for it during first run)

Comment: @snachmsm I have checked it on other app. Only realme 5 is giving this error. My app worked good on friend device. Any tips on how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't have a clue how to fix it, but you can detect if `Intent` will be handled by problematic app (use `resolveActivity`) and show some hint or just don't enable multi check. another approach is to write own picker, internal-only (but I'm not shure is this is compatible/possible with Scoped Storage on newer Android versions). This is a problem in 3rd-party app, you can't force anything on it, maybe have hope for its update :)

Comment: Its happening with Samsung A50 with Android 9 also.